# What are the form elements called?

Tags: html, forms, angularjs, input

This is silly, but I'm about to explode - inputs, selects, textareas, checkboxes, radio buttons... what is the general name of this type of elements?

I'm creating an AngularJS set of form/input directives that wrap single form field in an object called "input", which consists of "element"-DOM, "scope"-Scope and I want to be able to extract its form element like input, select, etc., but I can't find a proper name for it...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by what is general name of this type of element? they are pretty self explanatory?

Comment: well... apple, orange and pear are called fruit - input, select and textarea are called? :)

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: They're commonly called "form elements". What do you need the name for?

Comment: @Harry I can, but which part and what for really :)

Comment: @Juhana I need it to be able to name my variables and functions properly so the code is kept clean and slick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called “controls” in [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.2). HTML5 uses the same word, as well as the longer “form control”, but it has some more fine-grained terminology for “[form-associated elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-associated-element)”. In practice, controls are often called “form fields”.

The use of “form” in the names is partly misleading, since controls are syntactically permitted outside any forms, too, and such controls can be successfully used when handled with client-side JavaScript.

Comment: that's the type of answer that I was looking for, thanks, now I can sleep calmly

Answer (score 0):

They are called form controls or form elements or html inputs tags

Comment: Form controls is the only correct term. A form element is `<form>` itself. Inputs don't include `<select>`.